# Java Serializable Object not being received or sent to client android application

Tags: java, android, serialization

My Java Server runs a thread that simply creates an Order Object which takes four parameters. This Object is then sent through the ObjectOutputStream with the writeObject() method call (Order implements Serializable). I am not sure of the issue at hand, as the Object is not read/received at the client side. I tested this function with a String object and it worked fine. I believe it might have to do something with my Order class implementation. I have provided the code below for review:

Order class

```
public class Order implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 345634l;
    String cuisine;
    String description;
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;

    public Order(String cuis,String descr,int min,int max){
        cuisine = cuis;
        description = descr;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public void setCuisine(String c){
        cuisine = c;
    }

    public String getCuisine(){
        return cuisine;
    }

    public void setDescription(String d){
        description = d;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setMinPrice(int c){
        min = c;
    }

    public int getMin(){
        return min;
    }

    public void setMac(int x){
        max = x;
    }

    public int getMax(){
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return cuisine + "\n" + description + "\n" + min + "\n" + max + "\n" + "$";
    }
}
```

ListSender Thread (Server side)

```
class ListSender extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {                
            try {                 
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                Order r = new Order("Indian","Spicy Madras",4,9);
                orderList.add(r);
                oos.writeObject(r);
                oos.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MessageHandler Thread (Android Client-side)

```
class MessageHandler extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
            int orderHead = 0;
            String item = "";

            public Void doInBackground(Void... param){
                try{
                    serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr,portNumber);
                    ObjectInputStream ois = new  ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    Order e = (Order) ois.readObject();
                    onPostExecute(e.toString());
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

        public void onPostExecute(String s){
            foodList += s + "\n";
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        message.setText(foodList);
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I hope this information is sufficient for anybody to analyze and possibly explain an alternative or improved version of this code.

Comment: You should close your outputstram in a finally block... How do you notify your handler, that there is new information ?

Comment: Is any of this code actually being executed? Hard to believe. But in any case you should chia with a single object stream at each end for the life of the socket, not a new one per message.

Comment: yes the code is being executed and runs without errors. I have added the close() method but a SocketException gets thrown.

Answer (score -1):

Solution Found:

Make sure that all remote classes that are used in Serialization should also have the same package name.

Comment: So you were getting an exception and didn't bother to mention it in the question?